# Application can't find an assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, wse

I have an ASP.NET MVC application, which uses one old service (Web Services Enhancements, WSE). Right now I try to move this application to Azure. When I try to call web-service, which use WSE, I get an error:

```
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The value of the property 'type' cannot be parsed. The error is: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Services2, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error: 


Line 62:     <webServices>
Line 63:       <soapExtensionTypes>
Line 64:         <add type="Microsoft.Web.Services2.WebServicesExtension, Microsoft.Web.Services2, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" priority="1" group="High" />
Line 65:       </soapExtensionTypes>
Line 66:     </webServices>
```

so, application can't load this assembly. I checked bin folder - file Microsoft.Web.Services2.dll exists there. How to fix this problem? Maybe something like, but don't understand how:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Core" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the correct version of the Microsoft.Web.Services2.dll assembly?

Comment: how to check which version is added to my project (or bin folder)?

Comment: Check the Version info in Explorer's property page for the DLL file.

Comment: version is 2.0.5050.0. I have changed to <add type="Microsoft.Web.Services2.WebServicesExtension, Microsoft.Web.Services2, Version=2.0.5050.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" priority="1" group="High" />. Now error is similar ("Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Services2, Version=2.0.5050.0,....")

Comment: Verify that your reference is set to `Always Copy` (right click on the reference and select Properties).

Comment: yes, "Always copy" is set, no helped